# Jekyll for loop - multiple arrays

Tags: jekyll

In Jekyll, I have a small blog system going with two categories: `blog` and `portfolio`. I have two pages that will render the posts for these categories, with a `for` loop that looks something like this:

```
{% for post in site.categories['blog'] %}
…
{% endfor %}
```

On my home page, I want to show the latest post in the `blog` category. However, I want my blog to contain some of my photography too - these will exist as posts, but most of the time they have no title or body content - they are just an image. I do not want those posts to show up on the home page.

Effectively, I only want the latest blog post to show up on the home page, excluding all photography posts. I am considering my options for this:

1. Use two categories: `blog` and `photos`. However, how would I then make my blog page show posts from both of these categories? I would effectively need to merge the arrays `site.categories['blog']` and `site.categories['photos']`, and put those into a `for` loop - but is that possible?
2. Keep one category: `blog`, but in some other way, exclude posts without a title from appearing on the home page. But how do you do that?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

On the blog page you can use:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
…
{% endfor %}
```

To retrieve all posts and show them all. If you want to filter more (say, you have a third category you wouldn't want to show on this page:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
    {% if post.categories contains 'post' or post.categories contains 'photos' %}
       ...
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward approach here is to use [Jekyll categories](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/#predefined-variables-for-posts).

Put your posts into subdirectories of the _posts folder:

```
_posts/
    blog/
        post.md
    photos/
        photo.md
```

Then in your index.html or anywhere else you can refer to the separate categories as follows:

```
<h1>Blog</h1>

{% for post in site.categories.blog %}
    {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}

<h2>Photos</h2>

{% for photo in site.categories.photos %}
    {{ photo.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

And you can access all posts using `site.posts`.

For a relevant github issue "Multiple _posts directories" see
https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1819#issuecomment-30441840.